# Exchange 2010 - Change "Conversation View" default setting in Outlook Web App

Tags: email, iis, exchange-2010, group-policy

I'm converting an organization to Exchange from an older Linux-based Sendmail/Dovecot POP3 setup. In an attempt to ease the transition, I'd like to leverage Outlook Web App to help acclimate users to the concepts of server-based mail.

One of the issues I've encountered in training is the default *Conversation View* setting in OWA. This collapses/threads messages in a way that is extremely confusing for the users in *this* environment. Changing this setting individually is easy, as detailed below...

Is there a way to disable this view or deselect it as the default organization-wide?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/f5540de4-c333-4cf2-896b-45b5683b120e/) in which a MSFT PFE chimed in - you can't.

Brian Day, an Exchange PFE, says:

> You cannot disable it for everyone at this time. I would suggest
>   asking the users to give it a good month of use, and give it an honest
>   chance.
>
> Conversation view may takes some time for some people to
>   figure out, but the majority of the time people end up being far more
>   productive with it. Lots of real life people studies went into
>   observing how people were productivity-wise with and without it before
>   making it the default view.